# django-countries cannot get country name

Tags: django

Based on the [`django-countries`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-countries/) documentation,

```
>>> person.country
Country(code='NZ')
>>> person.country.name
u'New Zealand'
```

should be a way to retrieve the unicode for the country name. However, when I try it i get

```
>>> obj.country
Country(code='AX')
>>> obj.country.name
<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x91b81ac>
```

I checkout out countries.py and saw that the choices look like this:

```
('AX', ugettext_lazy('\xc5land Islands'))
```

Even using `print object.country.name` prints the same object. Why is it not working?

edit: Sorry, i just put the name object as a sample :p

Comment: I don't think object is a reserved word, but can you try giving it another name just to be sure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Call unicode() on it

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/unicode/#translated-strings

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy

u = ugettext_lazy('hello')
print u
# out: <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x158edd0>

print unicode(u)
# out: u'hello'
```

Normally not an issue if rendered in a template.